# Error when starting Report Builder - what is the reason?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have configured Reporting Services to allow users to use "Report Builder" application.
Users can see the "Report Builder" button (which links to **http://example.com/ReportServer/ReportBuilder/ReportBuilder.application**)

If I click on the button, everything works correctly on my machine.
If I log in using another person's account - everything still works correctly.
But if that person connects using his/her own PC he/her gets the error listed below.

```
=========
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
    Windows             : 5.1.2600.196608 (Win32NT)
    Common Language Runtime     : 2.0.50727.3625
    System.Deployment.dll       : 2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000)
    mscorwks.dll            : 2.0.50727.3625 (GDR.050727-3600)
    dfdll.dll           : 2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000)
    dfshim.dll          : 4.0.31106.0 (Main.031106-0000)

SOURCES
    Deployment url          : https://www.example.com/ReportServer/ReportBuilder/ReportBuilder.application

ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of https://www.example.com/ReportServer/ReportBuilder/ReportBuilder.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Downloading https://www.example.com/ReportServer/ReportBuilder/ReportBuilder.application did not succeed.
        + The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.
        + The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
    No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
    There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
    * [2012-01-20 09:55:06] : Activation of https://www.example.com/ReportServer/ReportBuilder/ReportBuilder.application has started.

ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [2012-01-20 09:55:06] System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentDownloadException (Unknown subtype)
        - Downloading https://www.example.com/ReportServer/ReportBuilder/ReportBuilder.application did not succeed.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadAllFiles()
            at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.Download(SubscriptionState subState)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadManifestAsRawFile(Uri& sourceUri, String targetPath, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, ServerInformation& serverInformation)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDeploymentManifestDirectBypass(SubscriptionStore subStore, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, SubscriptionState& subState, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, ServerInformation& serverInformation)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDeploymentManifestBypass(SubscriptionStore subStore, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, SubscriptionState& subState, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.Net.WebException
        - The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.
        - Source: System
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException
        - The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
        - Source: System
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, Exception exception)
            at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
            at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
            at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
            at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
            at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
            at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
            at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
            at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
            at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
            at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
            at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
            at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
            at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
            at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
            at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
            at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
            at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
            at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
            at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
            at System.Net.TlsStream.CallProcessAuthentication(Object state)
            at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
            at System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult result)
            at System.Net.TlsStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
            at System.Net.PooledStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
            at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(Boolean async)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
    No transaction information is available.


=========
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have an invalid (possibly self-signed?) SSL certificate on your server. Presumably it works on your PC because you have [installed the certificate](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpsanders/archive/2009/09/16/troubleshooting-asp-net-the-remote-certificate-is-invalid-according-to-the-validation-procedure.aspx) but your users have not. If this is correct, then you need to either get a valid certificate or tell your users to install the invalid one.

Getting a valid certificate would be the preferred solution, of course, otherwise you are encouraging your users to ignore security warnings.